# SmartGwt using Netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, smartgwt

I have a question please. 
I started working with SmartGWT. I want to add "the SmartGWT widgets" to the palette of "Netbeans" and use the drag-and-drop to construct my GUI (like in Swing (Java)). Can I do it? If Yes, How? .

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Drag and Drop feature of Widgets ,No need to add them to Netbeans(and don't know even how to do that ).

For that  [GWT Designer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/) is already there  and you can use Gwt designer with the SmartGwt .

Here is an [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq0UNdBwbYY) about that and

one more link for [GWT Designer + Smart GWt 3.0](http://idarkcell.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/gwt-designer-smartgwt-3-0/)